# How can I test a callback inside a promise resolve block

Tags: testing, jestjs, promise

I have the following module

```
import { Intent, Position } from '@blueprintjs/core';
import { createToaster } from '@hcfy/create-toaster';
import { MessageContent } from './types';

/** Singleton toaster instance. Use AppToaster.show() to add new message to the queue */
export const AppToaster = createToaster({
  className: 'app-toaster',
  position: Position.TOP,
});

export default class NotificationService {
  // this general function is used by message feature throughout the app
  public static showMessage(intent: Intent, message: MessageContent, timeout: number = 10000) {
    AppToaster.then((toaster) => {
      toaster.show({
        intent,
        message,
        timeout,
      });
    });
  }
}
```

I want to test NotificationService.showMessage and expect toaster.show to be called with thest parameters. How can I do that? I tried to search for a solution and even tried ChatGPT, but everything I found is about testing for promise resolve, and calling of a pre-existant callback, but here AppToaster is returning a promise that has the callback we want to test.

How can I mock toaster.show in this case?